# vsFlexGridPro7 how to enter legal lic-code in Win7-64bits

Tags: vb6, grid, windows-7-x64, ocx

I need to maintain an old vbp (vb6) project that uses the purchased videosoft vsFlexGridPro7 ocx (not the free msFlexGrid included in vb6pro).
This was working fine in WinXpPro and even in WinVista.

But my pc has crashed and now the new one runs Win7 64bits.

The original setup.exe from Videosoft (maybe using 16bits) doesn't run, and without running this setup I don't know other way to enter my legal lic code.

Then my vbp shows error (thinking I'm running the unregistered version) when running in vb6IDE or tryng to compile.

So, several related questions...

1.- any way to enter the lic codes without run setup.exe?

2- any way to run setup.exe? (not in an virtual machine....)

These grid don't use DB, "only" the LIGHT version (Vsflex7L.ocx), all code managed.

btw I think videosoft.com is closed, ComponentOne sells an version 8, but is expensive and 1.- not sure if it will be ease the conversion and 2.- if Videosoft is out of business don't appears as a good purchase.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use a VM?  I think that Win7 Professional, Enterprise and Ultimate allow you to download Virtual PC with a Windows XP VM free.  On the other hand, you might be able to run the setup.exe program in compatibility mode (I think you right click on the EXE, and choose the Window version).

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for your fast reply.

"compatibility mode" doesn't works, I've tested several ways but I think the setup.exe have some 16bits (?) components or so.

Of course I've try the VM way, installing also vb6pro  msdn + vs6-sp4, and in an simple test the grid works without the warning, but the project is quite complex and I will prefer run it in an "normal" environment, for sure it is the way to go if no other solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think VideoSoft are "out of business".  If I remember correctly they merged with another company (APEX) and changed name to ComponentOne, so you may be eligible for an "upgrade version" instead of a full new license.

Comment: In the ComponentOne site if you search using vsflexgrid or flexgrid nothing returns, and the chat is closed.
Anyway I've found an upgrade in ComponentSource (similar name!) but it's very expensive.
I will try to contact ComponentOne later.

Thanks.

Comment: The search is not working, but I've found this
http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/FlexGridWinForms/
that will be similar (but related to .NET)

Comment: ComponentOne is the Company! Yes... VSFlexGrid http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/vsflexgrid8/#!Documents/overview1.htm
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

We also faced exact same problem...our old VB app uses some of very old controls which are developed long time back ( 16 bit setup ). We ended up writing a installer for installing the files ( we ended up using the installsheild to create a setup) we got the list of files from original install locations ( install.txt). As far as license goes you can copy the license.bat file from original install location to c:\windows\system folder. Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your solution, I need investigate where is the install.txt and license.bat that you mention, but in this moment I've a lot of other troubles.

At the moment I try to use the Mark comment suggestd, using a WinXP in an Win7Pro and so on, but parked due tue other problems.

Thanks for share your experience.